# Extract the content of SQL aggregation expression in PHP by using relugar expression

Tags: php, regex, recursion, preg-match-all

I want to extract a content inside some function such as SUM, AVG, COUNT of a SQL query expression in PHP. For example `SUM(A+B)` -> `A+B` or `SUM(SUM(A))` -> `SUM(A)` and `A`.

I have used a function `preg_match_all` with a regular expression as follows:

`#(SUM|sum|AVG|avg|MIN|min|MAX|max|COUNT|count)\((.*?)\)#`

It works very well with a single function such as `SUM(A)`, but not for a multiple function case `SUM(SUM(A))`. The result of `SUM(SUM(A))` is `SUM(A`. It looks like `preg_match_all` only recognizes the first `)` and skip others next `)`.

Is there any way or any function help me to extract the content of the function in multiple function case?

Comment: cut your conditional size in half by using a case-insensitive pattern.  So how much have your researched about recursive patterns?  Please offer an sample input string that contains multiple "matchable" substrings and state your exact desired output.  Please show your coding attempt.

Comment: Use `/(sum|avg|min|max|count)\((.*)\)/i` https://regex101.com/r/zu1tjU/1/

Comment: @Mohammad Please never post solutions as comments.  p.s. there is no recursion in your pattern.  (please remove)

Comment: Your question is Unclear and incomplete.  Please improve your question. 
 Search this site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+regex+recursion

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that. I am new with regex. By the way, thank you all. I have found the answer in your comments.

Comment: @mickmackusa I think that is enough for me to find an answer. Thank you. How can I close this topic?

Comment: You are able to withdraw your question.